# Why do I get a Syntax error with masm macro?

Tags: assembly, syntax, macros, x86, masm

I am trying to code a MACRO called Prompt. It takes in three parameters, prints all of them to the console, and then reads in a string.

```
WriteStr MACRO text
  push edx
  mov edx, OFFSET text
  call WriteString 
  pop edx
ENDM

mPrompt MACRO name, subject, buffer
  push ecx

  ; Prompt
  WriteStr promptStr
  WriteStr name
  WriteStr subject

  ; Get the user input
  mov edx, OFFSET buffer
  movzx ecx, maxChars 
  call ReadString

  pop ecx
  call Clrscr
ENDM

main PROC
  call Clrscr
  ...
  mPrompt nameStr, name, nameBuff
  ...
  exit
main ENDP
```

However, I get a syntax error at `mPrompt nameStr, name, nameBuff`
How do I fix this?

Comment: Macro `mPrompt` seems to be using another macro `WriteStr`. Where is `WriteStr` defined?

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right let me add that.

Comment: Try using something other than `name` which is a reserved work in MASM.

Comment: work = word oops

Comment: Thanks, i'll see if that is the problem.

Comment: Turns out, it was. I just changed "name" to "sub" and it compiled perfectly. thanks.